# Why is it the [Kevin] Bacon Number and where does it come from?

Tags: kevin-bacon

For those who may not be familiar, if you get on to google and type any actor's name followed by "bacon number", google gives you the number of movies that separates that actor from Kevin Bacon. This even seems to go back to a larger media phenomenon of counting the direct and indirect collaborations with Kevin Bacon not related to google alone.

My question is, was there some film or event that started off this whole Bacon number? What triggered it off? Why Kevin Bacon and not somebody else?

Comment: The question isn't about a website, it's about the Bacon number, which is definitely Movie & TV related. The poster may have first been introduced to the concept via Google search, but the question is about the concept, not Google search.

Comment: Even if it is on-topic, this question shows exactly zero research effort. Searching "bacon number" in Google immediately gives everything you could possibly want to know about it in the form of several websites and the Wikipedia article Walt has used in his answer below.

Comment: As in, why Kevin Bacon. Why not someone else, like say Eric Roberts? There must be other actors equally connecting to stars through various movies. Why Kevin Bacon?

Comment: @Walt, which website are you referring to? (Please don't say Google or Wikipedia)

Comment: @Barry The question is specifically talking about Google... so perhaps if you reframe the question to be about the Bacon Number in general and remove the Google reference? Why Google chooses to have a one-box for the Bacon Number has nothing to do with M&TV.

Comment: @Barry *"Why Kevin Bacon?"* This wasn't planned. It was a fun little game a few guys came up with that involved a prolific actor. They *could've* picked some other prolific actor, sure, but they didn't. It just happened to be Bacon. A lot of viral things online are born out of whims.

Comment: @Catija *"Even if it is on-topic, this question shows exactly zero research effort."* - Which is not a reason for closing, though. The "trivia" close-vote means *"noone cares about this at all"*, it does *not* mean *"the answer is found by Google/Wikipedia"*.

Comment: Neither do I see the argument of this question being about some arbitrary third-party site and not about Movies & TV directly (an argument I tried to work against by elaborating the question a little more) reflected in the close-votes at all yet, which are all for "trivia" and none for "unrelated third-party site". "Trivia" is *not* the catch-all off-topic reason to be used when one is too lazy to come up with a genuine close-reason.

Comment: Great Scott, that's a whole lot of comments! I thank you all. I didn't imagine mentioning Google could lead people to think about the question being directed towards Google. I saw Google simply as the tool to find the Bacon Number, just like you find movies.stackexchange. @Walt, that Interview of Kevin Bacon was what seems to be the start of this viral trend. I thank you for that and accept it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Bacon Number was inspired by [Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Degrees_of_Kevin_Bacon), a popular parlor game that was based on the assumption that any actor could be linked to Kevin Bacon in 6 steps via their roles. Wikipedia details its origin:

> In a January 1994 Premiere magazine interview about the film The River Wild, Kevin Bacon commented that he had worked with everybody in Hollywood or someone who's worked with them. On April 7, 1994, a lengthy newsgroup thread headed "Kevin Bacon is the Center of the Universe" appeared. **The game was created in early 1994 by three Albright College students, Craig Fass, Brian Turtle, and Mike Ginelli.** According to an interview with the three in the spring 1999 issue of the college's magazine, The Albright Reporter, **they were watching *Footloose* [starring Bacon] during a heavy snowstorm. When the film was followed by *The Air Up There* [another Bacon movie], they began to speculate on how many movies Bacon had been in and the number of people he had worked with.** "It became one of our stupid party tricks I guess. People would throw names at us and we'd connect them to Kevin Bacon."
>
> The trio wrote a letter to talk show host Jon Stewart, telling him that "Kevin Bacon was the center of the entertainment universe" and explaining the game. They appeared on The Jon Stewart Show and The Howard Stern Show with Bacon to explain the game. Bacon admitted that he initially disliked the game because he believed it was ridiculing him, but he eventually came to enjoy it.

The whole thing is an homage to ['six degrees of seperation'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation), the theory that *every person is connected to any other person* by 6 steps or less. The three college students picked Bacon to illustrate the theory in the world of film because, as specified above, they realized he was in a lot of things. Happenstance made it about Bacon and not about some other prolific actor, and it was fun enough to become viral.

Comment: As in, why Kevin Bacon. Why not someone else, like say Eric Roberts? There must be other actors equally connecting to stars through various movies. Why Kevin Bacon?

Comment: @Barry The article clearly states: "Kevin Bacon commented that he had worked with everybody in Hollywood or someone who's worked with them."... so people decided to see if that was true or not...

Comment: @Barry Now I see... However, your question was not about the origin of Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon. It was about the origin of Google's Bacon Number, and I've answered it as I understood it. If you wanted to know why Bacon was specifically chosen for this game, the whole question probably needs to be rephrased.

Comment: As a note, this appears to be the original news group mentioned in the Wikipedia article: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.arts.movies/-qNue6RwTn8[1-25]

Comment: And as a sidenote, it could and *had* been done with other actors (and other famous people) in many other online generators. But the Bacon one started the trend.

Comment: As an interesting side note, the Bacon number wasn't first. There's no evidence I know of that they were inspired by it, but the [Erdős number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős_number) (for mathematicians who had written papers together) had been around since 1969. There's even an [Erdős–Bacon number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Bacon_number) that unifies them.

Comment: Here's a list of 1000 best centres of degrees of separation as calculated using IMDB database. Kevin Bacon is number 411: http://oracleofbacon.org/center_list.php

Comment: @SevenSidedDie obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/599/) link